# Can "resemblance" be used interchangeably with "semblance" in the idiomatic context of a comparison to a former self?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, synonyms

For example,

> After the war, Dresden retained little [re]semblance of its former self.

> Although he'd quit drinking, his lifestyle continued in some [re]semblance of its former self.

I came across "resemblance" used this way and it sounded odd to me.

Comment: No, Max.

"Resemblance to" or "semblance of" and still, they're not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At their core, the terms **resemblance** and **semblance** do not really belong to the same cluster of synonyms.

> **Semblance** is almost invariably used to contrast *appearance* with reality: a doubtful assertion that has the *semblance* of truth; an
> enemy who cloaks threats with the *semblance* of civility. It may,
> however, be used to mean outward *appearance* without any suggestion
> of falseness: The faceless person in her dreams began to acquire the
> *semblance* of her dead brother.
>
> **Resemble** is closely related to *compare*. Its stress, however, is on a closer likeness, indicating that one thing *compares* in a number
> of ways to something else. Also, *resemble* carries a stronger visual
> suggestion than *compare*: children who *resemble* their mother; a
> child who *resembled* someone I used to know; an argument that
> *resembles* an earlier but now discredited theory.

[Source - *[Choose the Right Word](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/choose-the-right-word-s-i-hayakawa/1002516046?ean=9780062731319)*]

Comment: Interesting point. I agree--thanks for confirming my intuition.